# getting update with webhook

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telegram-bot

When I get an update from the webhook, the update is empty with zero ID, The bot successfully pairs with my webhook

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Update update)

    {}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]Update update)

    {}
```

All Newtonsoft libraries are also installedAll Newtonsoft libraries are also installed

I ran a test bot and converted the update to a string and sent it to my chat as hard code.I ran a test bot and converted the update to a string and sent it to my chat as a hard code, but the update value was empty.

My project is an ASP.NET Core

Comment: `"I ran a test bot and converted the update to a string and sent it to my chat as hard code.I ran a test bot and converted the update to a string and sent it to my chat as a hard code, but the update value was empty"` How your issue can be reproduced? How you are sending request to web hook and what you are sending? Please include the relevant code snippet in order to test your scenario, because here what you are saying just cannot be visualized what exactly causin the issue.